# Put attributes of jquery selector in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I want to save the ID of each input element of the form which form element I clicked into an array.

```
    var element = $(element);
    var $formID = element.closest('form').prop("id") || "";
    var formElementsIDs = []; // What to do?
```

There, I got the form ID. How do I get each form element from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.map()` along with `.get()` to collect all the input element's id in an array,

```
 var formElementsIDs = element.closest('form').find('input').map(function(){
   return this.id || '';
 }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `.get()` with appropriate selector to get all the ids in array :

```
var ids=$(element).closest('form').find('input').map(function() {
    return this.id; 
}).get();
```